# How to show images from a folder using Razor MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using Razor MVC and I would like to show images from "~/Content/uploads" folder.
I came up with the following solution:

```
@foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in (new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads"))
                                    .GetFiles().Where(x => x.Extension == ".jpg"))) {
    <img src="/@fileInfo
               .FullName
               .Substring(Server.MapPath("~/").Length)
               .Replace("\\", "/")"
         width="100">
}
```

The problem with the code is that I am taking the full file path
and I am removing the Server.MapPath() prefix.

How can I simplify this code?

Comment: If possible, either accept the answer you have found appropriate or post the solution, if you have came across other than the answers posted here.

Comment: I agree with you @Vikram

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) class that is available on Razor pages.

```
@foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads"), "*.jpg"))
{
    var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);
    <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Content/uploads/{0}", img.Name))" />
}
```

Comment: Good one. Worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

@Rowan Freeman answer helped me for `jpg` image file. But This is for multiple files:

**View images with multiple filters**

```
@{

string supportedExtensions = "*.jpg,*.gif,*.png,*.bmp,*.jpe,*.jpeg,*.ico";

foreach (string imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images/store/"), "*.*", 
SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => supportedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s)
.ToLower())))
{
    var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);
    <img style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/images/
    store/{0}", img.Name))" />
}

}
```

Hope helps some one.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4617227/2218697)